# How can I know ajax modal popup is opened?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

How can I know ajax modal popup is opened? Help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Modal Popup Extender has no direct way to determine its visibility state from code behind. [This post describes a workaround for that.](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2009/05/05/check-modal-popup-extender-visibility-from-code-behind.aspx).